# Fast report error

Tags: c#, report

I have [FastReport.NET](http://bit.ly/cKP3lV) it is linked to my C# 2010.
When I try to drag my report from the toolbox onto the Windows application, it gives me the following error:

> Type or namespace Report does not exist.

I have tried adding the .dll references of fast report and it still gives me this error. Could it be because im using the Fast Report.net demo, or what code am i missing.

How do I fix this problem?

Comment: Have you tried the support options from FastReport.Net? They seem to have a support forum, FAQ section etc –

Answer (score 0):

Right click on your project's solution explorer and select **add reference** and browse and add **.dll** for the same and press **Ok**.
After then you won't have this error no longer.

Comment: Thanks for the reply, i have added all the .dll of fast report and still the same problem, could this be coz im using FastReport.net demo?

Comment: as far as I think this can not be the problem, you need to check the references first.