# C# vs Fast report error

Tags: c#

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Fast report error](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11716970/fast-report-error)

I have fast report.net DEMO it is linked to my C# 2010. When I try to drag my report from the toolbox onto the Windows application, it gives me the following error:

Type or namespace Report does not exist in FastReport.

How do I fix this problem?

I have tried adding the .dll references of fast report and it still gives me this error.
Could it be because im using the Fast Report.net demo, or what code am i miising.

Please someone help me :-(

Comment: You've already asked this question: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11716970/fast-report-error

Comment: Yes i have but like i said in this one, i tried adding the .dll references and it still doesnt work

Comment: If you don't get (good) answers, then please improve your question (add additional information) instead of creating a duplicate.